# Biases of estimators of the exponential random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be independent random variables, each distributed as $Exp(\lambda)$. I am given 2 estimators of $\lambda$:
$$\hat{\lambda_1}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_i}$$
$$\hat{\lambda_2}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}$$
I have to calculate the bias of each estimator.
$$Bias_1=E(\hat{\lambda_1})-\lambda=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\lambda^{-1}}-\lambda=\frac{1}{n}n\lambda-\lambda=\lambda-\lambda=0$$
$$Bias_2=E(\hat{\lambda_2})-\lambda=\frac{n}{\frac{n}{\lambda}}-\lambda=0$$
Used properties:

1. $E(X_i)=\lambda^{-1}$
2. $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)=\frac{n}{\lambda}$ as the sum of iid exponential variables has a gamma distribution with parameters $n,\lambda$

However, in the next part, I am told that $\hat{\lambda_2}$ is biased and I have to modify it in order to obtain an unbiased estimator. What did I do wrong in bias calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be assuming that $E[g(Z)]=g(E[Z])$ for any (measurable) function $g$ but this is **not true** unless $g$ is linear.

For the first estimator the bias is not well defined since $1/X_i$ has an [inverse exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_exponential_distribution), whose expected value does not exist.

For the second estimator, it helps to note $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim$ [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)$(n,\lambda)$ (using the $(\alpha,\beta)$ shape-rate parametrization), so  $1/\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim $[Inv-Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution)$(n,\lambda).$

Comment: Thank you, I get my mistake. I am also asked which estimator would I prefer to choose. Is it better to choose a well-defined bias? Or should I calculate MSE of each to decide?

Comment: The bias of the first estimator is essentially infinite (note $1/X_i$ is a special case of Inv-Gamma$(1,\lambda)).$ Up to you which criterion you want to use (of course MSE and bias are related since MSE is bias+variance^2).